# EF Core - unique, indexed, auto-generated guid column that is not the primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am migrating from .NET EF to EF CORE. I have a working solution that automatically generates a unique GUID aside from its primary key. Below is the solution.

```
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
```

However, when i tried to migrate to EF Core, i am getting an error message when inserting the data: >SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TenantId', table 'DBContext.dbo.Tenants'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Here's my new code:

```
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
```

Fluent:

```
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<Tenant>()
     .HasIndex(t => t.TenantId)
     .IsUnique();
    builder.Entity<Tenant>()
     .Property(t => t.TenantId)
     .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

This is inserted by using:

```
         _context.Tenants.Add(tenant);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Is this something that is not supported by EF Core and requires a workaround?

Comment: How and where is the unique GUID generated? With your setup, EFC expects it to be provided by database (with column `DEFAULT` or something).

Comment: In my .NET Framework version, it is generated automatically by the database. Wouldn't this 'ValueGeneratedOnAdd()' generate it?

Comment: I think you need `HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()")` instead.

Comment: I tried that also but still has an SqlException cannot insert NULL.

Comment: It has to be applied on table creation or with migration. Otherwise it would not work. The whole idea is that EF sends `NULL` value (or nothing) during the `INSERT` to let column `DEFAULT` clause do the job. If you look at your db table definition, you should see something like `[TenantId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL`.

Comment: yeah. i needed to recreate the migration for all these to apply. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On your new code you don't have the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` annotation. Your code should be:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Isn't it the same with the addition of `builder.Entity<Tenant>()
            //    .Property(t => t.TenantId)
            //    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();`? I tried that before, it produces the same error.

Comment: ok, so i need to recreate the whole migration from scratch for this changes to reflect in the database.

Comment: I haven't used a guid before as Identity column in EF Core so I can' say for sure..but if you try it give us feedback please :)

Comment: "Identity value generation can only be used with signed integer properties"

Answer (score -3):

I think the reason why you are getting the Null is because you are supposed to instantiate the value of the Guid. 
something like

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid TenantId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
```